# MySQL select by count of elements in JSON array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I currently have this JSONs in my database

| user | info |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ["subscriptions": [{"user": 1}, {"user": 2}]] |
| 1 | [] |
| 2 | null |

And I want something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_info 
WHERE count(subscriptions) == 2
```

(select by count of elements in "subscriptions" key of JSON)

I've tried with JSON_SEARCH, but didn't managed to get something to work

Comment: *WHERE count(subscriptions) == 2* What do you mean? The amount of objects in "subscriptions" array?

Comment: yes, count of elements in "subscriptions" key of JSON

Comment: ```WHERE JSON_LENGTH(user_info.info, '$.subscriptions') = 2```. PS. Your value for user 0 must be an object, not an array. Array cannot contain named properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think your JSON format that you saved in DB is not proper JSON, Please validate the string in JSON validator online. Please check below screenshot

[image]

Correct JSON format should be

```
{"subscriptions": [{"user": 1}, {"user": 2}]}
```

Based on the JSON format provided below is the sql query for your requirement

```
SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE info is not null and JSON_LENGTH(JSON_EXTRACT(info, '$.subscriptions')) = 2
```

If above suggested format is not suitable for you, then use below:

```
[{"subscriptions": [{"user": 1}, {"user": 2}]}]
```

Then your query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE info is not null and JSON_LENGTH(info->'$[0].subscriptions') = 2
```

When you use any JSON format, make sure it is a valid format by using json validators,

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of occurrences of the key *user* by getting the difference between the `CHAR_LENGTH` of the info column and the `CHAR_LENGTH` of the *info* column (again) but this time, using `REPLACE` to replace any occurrence of *user* with the `LENGTH` of *user* using `SPACE`. The difference will essentially be the occurrence count of the static value *user*.

```
SELECT 
    user,
    info,   
    COALESCE(CHAR_LENGTH(info) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(info, 'user', SPACE(LENGTH('user')-1))), 0) AS user_count   
FROM user_info
```

**Result:**

| user | info | user_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ["subscriptions": [{"user": 1}, {"user": 2}]] | 2 |
| 1 | [] | 0 |
| 2 | null | 0 |
| 3 | ["subscriptions": [{"user": 1}, {"user": 2}, {"user": 3}]] | 3 |
| 4 | ["subscriptions": [{"user": 1}, {"user": 2} , {"user": 3}, {"user": 4}]] | 4 |

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ws5NJbHE).

Otherwise, you need to fix your `JSON` formatting in your array column to use the `JSON` functionality in MySQL.